# SVN automatic clone to ftp

Tags: svn, ftp, repository, svn-repository

I have a FTP-Server and a SVN Repository (RiouxSVN).

I want the SVN Repo to be cloned onto the FTP when i commit into the SVN Repo.

Thanks for every answer!

Edit:
I need only the latest version of trunk. I access the FTP Server via a url, username and password...

Comment: How do you access the FTP-server? Do you need a full copy from SVN repository (mirror) or only need the latest version (the content of `trunk` directory)?

Comment: I edited the Question...

Comment: I searched about RiouxSVN. It seems for me it's a provider and you can't create hooks. So I think you should do it on client-side. IMHO the one possibility is to create a svn-wrapper (script or similar) which do the copy to server. As I know there aren't client-side scripts in svn. But maybe an another: you create a repository on your machine (so you'll be the server) and after every commit you run an `svnsync` (on `post-commit` hook).

Comment: By 'clone I believe you mean checkout. You can easily do this with checkout. Checkout the repo FTP server; Create a script to run "svn update My_workspace" on FTP server. Schedule this script to run every 5 minuts or something.